# Why won't Pokemon appear without restarting Pokemon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go, technical-issues

When I drive around in a car with friends or sit at a Pokestop with lures, Pokemon don't always appear for me. All my friends seem to get Pokemon popping up, they end up having to tell me so I can restart the app and get them to show as well.

Also when we drive around, my character sometimes runes off from the path were going, while theirs run perfectly straight. so I pretty much cannot play the game other than sitting at Pokestops and restarting the app every 3 minutes.

Why is this? It is extremely annoying and is only happening to me. Any idea why? I have a iPhone 5s.

Comment: Yeah, Pokémon Go has a feature that prevents it from working well when it detects its user is playing while driving. I'm joking here, there's probably something wrong with your GPS. Still, you really shouldn't play and drive. You're endangering yourself and your surrounding.

Comment: im not the one driving tho. but yeah, its when we walk aswell and sit still.

Comment: The automatic soft ban for being caught driving while pokemonning persists for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Any other friend having the same phone as you. It sounds like your phone's GPS isn't as good as your friends' and it simply can' t keep up properly. Try running a maps app next time to see if I'm right.

Comment: hmm it seems fine. maybe its the operator?

Comment: @mikki, try turning off WiFi when you use a maps app. Those apps tend to scan for WiFi networks to more accurately guess your location.